# Is it possible to use NVDIMM to store data while using normal RAM for the OS?

Tags: memory

Can you split your RAM if you have 4GB of normal RAM and 4GB of NVDIMM? That way you can have the Linux use the normal ram and store data on the NVDIMM?

Comment: Not reliably, with a von Neumann architecture.

Comment: Which devices have 4G of regular ram and 4G of nvram?

Comment: Sorry, I updated my question. Found out I meant NVDIMM not NVRAM.

Comment: @Xen2050 I am referring to using normal RAM and NVDIMMs like those found here: https://www.micron.com/products/dram-modules/nvdimm#/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. [The kernel wiki](https://nvdimm.wiki.kernel.org/) provides an excellent resource on how to get started with this.

In a nutshell you need to inform the kernel that you want to partition some of the memory into a type 12 memory region. [Be sure you allocate the memory correctly](https://nvdimm.wiki.kernel.org/how_to_choose_the_correct_memmap_kernel_parameter_for_pmem_on_your_system). Then a pmem block device will show up in Linux. The wiki provides multiple methods of accessing data on from the `/dev/pmem0` device.

As davidgo pointed out, it seems hardware is more of an issue though. Getting your hands on NVDIMMs without buying a server through HPE or Dell is particularly hard. The motherboard must also support NVDIMMs for sending an ADR command to the NVDIMMs upon power failure. While Intel specifically lists Haswell/Broadwell as being compatible with NVDIMM technology it's my expectation that it should work on any future Intel Xeon CPUs as well.

Answer (score 1):

From what I have read it is entirely doable at a software level. (Linux creates block devices/structures to carve up and work with  nvdimms)

The question is thus "does hardware support it", and the unsatisfying  answer is "maybe/not yet" - as can be inferred from https://www.anandtech.com/show/12828/intel-launches-optane-dimms-up-to-512gb-apache-pass-is-here

Bearing in mind the limitations of mixing RAM types and their dependence on the way the hardware is built - the answer must be that the ability to mix and match will depend on the motherboard.

Comment: Can you point out any motherboards that explicitly support NVDIMMs? I've been unable to find any. Interesting link btw, thank you.

Comment: Your Google-Fu needs a lot of work - https://www.amazon.com/ASRock-Rack-Motherboard-Motherboards-EPC612D4U/dp/B00Z87EONE   https://www.amazon.com/ASRock-Rack-EP2C612D8-2T8R-Motherboard/dp/B012F8M1TC https://www.supermicro.com/products/nfo/Xeon_X9_E5.cfm?pg=MB http://www.tomsitpro.com/articles/hpe-nvdimm-micron-proliant-gen9,1-3215.html  https://tyan.com/Motherboards=S7100=S7100GM2NR https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_nkw=nvdimm+motherboard

Comment: Ahh, yes it does. Why does the motherboard need to explicitly support NVDIMMs, isn't it the same as normal memory with a NAND dump onboard? And in that case does the CPU need to as well?

Comment: No offense, but the comments section of a Superuser post is not an appropriate forum for Q/A - and the continued questions make me feel like an unpaid support person. https://software.intel.com/en-us/persistent-memory/support gives some definitive answers.

Comment: Your right, sorry. Just have so many questions I kind of got ahead of myself :). Thanks you the intel you've provided so far, as well as the links.